# How to run flutter app in iOS simulator in release mode?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

There is an issue with flutter apps on iOS 13 and above where we cannot launch the app for the second time if it's build in debug mode. So I use release build. This works when running on physical device. But I want to test in simulator but I am getting the following error: `Runner's architectures (arm64) include none that iPhone 14 Pro can execute (Intel 64-bit).`.

How to run this in simulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Flutter documentations it seems that it is not possible to run it in release mode. [Check this flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#release). Where you can find following statement `For mobile, release mode (which is not supported on the simulator or emulator)...`. Or you can as well follow [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11754) issue on flutter repository on Github.